# Doctrine one to many updating/removing/adding

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-many

At the moment im confused about how to manage the following:

In the application the user fills in a list of prefixes, he can add or delete prefixes. If the user clicks the submit button the form will be submitted.

Now the problem is that when a user deletes a prefix i dont get that id, i only receive the list of the prefixes the user wants.

What would be the efficiently way of handeling a remove with Doctrine (Arraycollection).

Comment: There's a lot of ways to process that kind of request. You could use hidden fields with the id's, you could use form events to diff the data you set (`POST_SET_DATA`), and compare it to the submitted data (`POST_SUBMIT`). It all depends on how you build the form, and how/where you store the data.